# Go to next edit text or dismiss keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, textfield

In my iOS app i want the keyboard to be dismissed when the user clicks return on the keyboard. Even better would be if it would go to the next Textfield and close the keyboard after that one. Is it possible with `swift`?
I already tried

```
self.myEditText.delegate = self;

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return false
}
```

But I get the Error: Type ViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: then conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` firstly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your `ViewController` class. like,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
...
```